# Multithreading in C++, receive message from socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, object, recv

I have studied Java for 8 months but decided to learn some c++ to on my spare time.

I'm currently making a multithreaded server in QT with minGW. My problem is that when a client connects, I create an instance of Client( which is a class) and pass the socket in the client class contructor.

And then I start a thread in the client object (startClient()) which is going to wait for messages, but it doesn't. Btw, startClient is a method that I create a thread from. See code below.

What happens then? Yes, when I try to send messages to the server, only errors, the server won't print out that a new client connects, and for some reason my computer starts working really hard. And qtcreator gets super slow until I close the server-program.

What I actually is trying to achieve is an object which derives the thread, but I have heard that it isn't a very good idea to do so in C++.

The listener loop in the server:

```
for (;;)
    {
        if ((sock_CONNECTION = accept(sock_LISTEN, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &AddressSize)))
        {
            cout << "\nClient connected" << endl;

            Client client(sock_CONNECTION); // new object and pass the socket
            std::thread t1(&Client::startClient, client); //create thread of the method
            t1.detach();
        }
    }
```

the Client class:

```
Client::Client(SOCKET socket)
{
    this->socket = socket;
    cout << "hello from clientconstructor ! " << endl;
}

void Client::startClient()
{
    cout << "hello from clientmethod ! " << endl;

    // WHEN I ADD THE CODE BELOW I DON'T GET ANY OUTPUT ON THE CONSOLE!
    // No messages gets received either.
    char RecvdData[100] = "";
    int ret;
    for(;;)
    {

        try
        {
            ret = recv(socket,RecvdData,sizeof(RecvdData),0);
            cout << RecvdData << endl;
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            cout << "Error sending message to client" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you never see any output from the Server likely means that your client is unable to connect to your Server in the first place.  Check that you are doing your IP addressing correctly in your connect calls.  If that looks good, then maybe there is a firewall blocking the connection.  Turn that off or open the necessary ports.

Your connecting client is likely getting an error from connect that it is interpreting as success and then trying to send lots of traffic on an invalid socket as fast as it can, which is why your machine seems to be working hard.

You definitely need to check the return values from accept, connect, read and write more carefully.  Also, make sure that you aren't running your Server's accept socket in non-blocking mode.  I don't think that you are because you aren't seeing any output, but if you did it would infinitely loop on error spawning tons of threads that would also infinitely loop on errors and likely bring your machine to its knees.

If I misunderstood what is happening and you do actually get a client connection and have "Client connected" and "hello from client method ! " output, then it is highly likely that your calls to recv() are failing and you are ignoring the failure.  So, you are in a tight infinite loop that is repeatedly outputting "" as fast as possible.

You also probably want to change your catch block to catch (...) rather than int.  I doubt either recv() or cout throw an int.  Even so, that catch block won't be invoked when recv fails because recv doesn't throw any exceptions AFAIK.  It returns its failure indicator through its return value.

Comment: Hi! There is no problem with the firewall because I have sent messages from the server directly when a client connects, and when I connected in telnet, I got the message from the server. But am I realy doing everything right with the object and threads? I achieve equal in java by deriving from thread but in c++ you should not do that or ?

Comment: Ok but if you look at the startCliebnt method, If I remove all the code except the cout "hello from client method, then it works and prints everything, but when I add the code below the comment, nothing at all gets printed. Isn't that weird?

Comment: I definitely agree with PDizzle that you need to dynamically allocate your Client at the very least using new().  I can't help you with the "proper" way to spawn a thread in C++ (although I'd be concerned about your std::thread variable also going out of scope -- make sure that's OK to do).  I'm a C guy, so I'd just call pthread_create() / pthread_detach() or their equivalent on Windows.

Comment: But you can use pthread in C++? Found this, wouldn't this be better than my class junk? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm

Comment: Yes, it's weird but you are likely in the crazy land of the undefined because your Client has likely been deallocated by the time your spawned thread tries touching its member variables.  Once it gets into its loop, I wouldn't be surprised that it outputs nothing because recv will likely return -1 and you will output "" as fast as possible forever.

Comment: You *CAN* use pthread if minGW implements it, as most C code is valid C++ code too.  I don't know if minGW implements pthreads or not.  On Windows there is always CreateThread().  Regardless, these are definitely the C way of spawning threads and your C++ elders might frown upon you for it. :)  These methods are obviously not cross platform too, while the C++ standard libraries or boost likely have cross platform capabilities.

Comment: you were right, i changed so if the recv return -1, it would print out error, and it print error as fast as possible ever! What is my next step now when we know what's wrong? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70880/discussion-between-jschultz410-and-johan).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `Client` object is going out of scope after you detach it.

```
if (/* ... */)
{
  Client client(sock_CONNECTION);
  std::thread t1(&Client::startClient, client);
  t1.detach();
} // GOING OUT OF SCOPE HERE
```

You'll need to create a pointer of your client object and manage it, or define it at a higher level where it won't go out of scope.

Comment: Ok but if you look at the startCliebnt method, If I remove all the code except the cout "hello from client method, then it works and prints everything, but when I add the code below the comment, nothing gets printed. Isn't that weird?

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised it's not crashing with this current logic state. It could be a race condition or other undefined behavior of the object no longer existing in the thread. The compiler could be optimizing the function and defines variables before the output which is why it's printing when you don't include the code . I'm pretty sure if you fix this issue you're not going to run into problems.

Comment: I think you might be right, But in Java I use to create an array of objects of a class, which extends thread, how could i achieve equal in C++?

Comment: It is not a good practice to extend `std::thread` in C++. Either make the objects hold a thread or make the class a functor, so that they can be invoked in a similar fashion to a `Runnable` in Java.

Comment: Ok but with "object hold a thread" , what exactly would that be? Isn't that what I've done, or what I have done? :P